# Loop Corrections to the Propagator and Vertex in $\phi^3$ theory (Srednicki)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, propagator

In chapter 14 of Srednicki's QFT textbook,  I don't know how to derive the Eq. 14.2.

[image]

I expand the correlation functions (or the functional generator), but I can't reach the same result.

I have the same problem in chapter 14, with the Eq. 16.1.

[image]

I don't know how to find these equations.

Comment: Look at the Feynman diagram Fig 14.1, for instance, and write down the amplitude.

Comment: I understand that this way you can get the formula. But, I thought that first the formula is obtained analytically and then the diagram.

Comment: Yes. But how does that matter? They are 2 different ways of describing the same thing.